# gnope for php-gtk2 is gone?

Tags: php, gtk2

where can i download the gnope installer to have the php-gtk2 in my machine ?, according to the online manual, it is found at gnope.org, but I am being redirected to this tradebit website,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnope/
http://web.archive.org/web/20070510013722/http://gnope.org/

Even seems to host the binary winstaller still.

Answer (score 2):

http://libki.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libki/libki;a=commitdiff;h=381f1a28d15d87bde4c36a9be0991af762b16109